# for loop speed and exponentiation in julia

Tags: for-loop, julia, precision

i timed the following code in julia:

```
function foo()
  for x=1:10^25
      y = 1 + 2
  end
end
```

the result seems unrealistic:

```
@time foo()
  0.017498 seconds (46.44 k allocations: 2.640 MiB)
```

if `1:10^25` creates a sequence/range of that length and the for loop iterates through that many elements how could it be so fast? also, `10^26` gives `-2537764290115403776` while `10^28` is positive (`4477988020393345024`) and `10^80` is `0`. shouldn't these trigger some overflow error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening here. Firstly, ranges are lazy, so it never constructs. Second of all, Julia uses 64 bit unchecked arithmetic (assuming 64 bit computer) for speed (same as C, Java, etc).

https://github.com/JeffreySarnoff/SaferIntegers.jl implements integers with overflow checks if you desire that behavior.

Comment: The additional thing is that the loop is optimized-out by the compiler which you can check by calling `@code_native foo()`.

Comment: If the compiler can figure out that your function has no return value and no side effects, then it can just skip the whole thing. Try this: `foo() == nothing`. This returns `true`, so the compiler could just replace your function with `nothing`. Looking at the output of `@code_native` and `@code_llvm` I'm not sure if it actually does that, but it is free to do so.